# Autopopulate records from MYSQL to HTML then update

Tags: javascript, php, mysql

I am trying to create an update form such that when I enter the id, it populates the rest of the fields automatically. Then I click update button to update.
So far I have created the insert and it works.

How do I start to create this update?
I am very stranded, any expert to assist me.

Here is my form:

```html
<form action="" method="Post" name="input">
        InsertID:<input type="text" name="ID" size="4" maxlength="4" /><br/>

        Polygon:<select name="Polygon">
                    <option value="Polygon001">Polygon 001</option>
               </select><br />

        F_name:<input type="text" name="fname" value="" /><br/>

        L_name:<input type="text" name="lname" value="Lname" /><br />

        Actype<select name="Type">
                <option value="Business">Business</option>
                <option value="Residential">Residential</option>
            </select><br />

        AcDesc:<textarea name="ActDesc" rows="5" cols="40">CO-worker.
             </textarea><br />

        S_date: <input type="date" name="sdate" /><br/>

        E_date: <input type="date" name="Edate" /><br />

        Duration: <input type="text" name="Duration" /><br />

        Status:<select name="Status">
                 <option value="Ongoing">On going</option>
                 <option value="Pending">Pending</option>
                 <option value="Finished">Finished</option>
                 <option value="Ignored">Ignored</option>
             </select>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
```

Here is my php code:

```php
$connection = mysql_connect("localhost","root","")
or die ("Couldn't connect to server");
$db = mysql_select_db("syrecuse", $connection)
or die ("Couldn't select database");

$Teritory=$_POST['Teritory'];

$fname=$_POST['fname'];

$lname=$_POST['lname'];

$Type=$_POST['Type'];

$ActDesc=$_POST['ActDesc'];

$sdate=$_POST['sdate'];

$Edate=$_POST['Edate'];

$Duration=$_POST['Duration'];

$Status=$_POST['Status'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO syrecuseone (Teritory, fname, lname, Type, ActDesc, sdate, 
            edate, Duration,status) VALUES ('$Teritory', '$fname', '$lname', '$Type', 
            '$ActDesc', '$sdate', '$edate', '$Duration', '$Status')";

if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
    die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
```

Comment: So if the ID already exists you want to update the values? And if it doesn't exist then create a new entry?

Comment: thanks for reply the id exist in the database...and i would want to update the auto populated records

Comment: This can be the best Christmas gift i can ever want...populate/update

Comment: The answer from @user3048611 will work for you. If your ID already exists you can update the record. If not, use an 'insert ... on duplicate key update...' statement.